# CopyHere not working as expected when copying fonts

Tags: vbscript

I made a script, which is supposed to copy a bunch of fonts to the Windows font folder. When I run it, I receive the output of the file names I would like copied, but nothing copies. It works when I remove the For loop, and specify file names. Any help appreciated.

```
Const FONTS = &H14&
sFolder = "c:\FontInstalls\"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(FONTS) 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each oFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
  If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "TTF" Then
    objFolder.CopyHere(oFile)
    wscript.echo(oFile)
  End if
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts need to be installed not copied. Copy the shell's objects rather than underlying files. The shell installs fonts copied into the fonts folder.

Here's the objects you need adding files to a zip.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"
```